# Iterate through Janus GridEx gridview

Tags: gridview, janus

I am using a Janus Gridview in which I am having 3 columns that is "Key", "Value" and selection(checkbox). I want to retrieve "Key" and "value" data for each selected rows that is against checked checkbox.

Comment: share the source code

Comment: Which language are you using Janus GridEx with?  (VB6, etc.)

Comment: I am using c#. I got the solution.  I am iterating like this 
for (int i = 0; i < summaryFinalGridEX.RowCount; i++)
{
            bool res = false;
            res = summaryFinalGridEX.GetRow(i).IsChecked; //finding if a row is checked or not.
  if (res == true)
              {
var temp = summaryFinalGridEX.GetRow(i); //gives checked row